# OK to ask people to write programs (not just code golf)?

Tags: discussion

Is it OK to ask a question like "Could you write a program that [does 
stuff]?"

Excluding code golf, most people seem to draw the line at actually 
writing a program, but is it OK to at least ask?

EDIT: Is it OK to look for a pair programming partner here?

Comment: The answer still no.

Answer (score 14):

No.

1. It's rude.
2. The system isn't designed for that sort of large-scale code sharing.
3. It's off-topic for Programmers.SE.

This isn't "Rent-A-Coder".

Answer (score 7):

What would be the point of such a question? The answers would boil down to "yep, I could" or "nope, I couldn't".

Comment: LOL! Ah, it's my 5th grade teacher again! Of course, I meant "would"? IE, the answer would be the program itself.

Comment: @barrycarter I wasn't sure. The way your question is worded read to me like you wouldn't actually ask people to write the code.

Comment: I just saw your point. I might ask people here if they COULD do it, and then contact them offsite to negotiate. But, no, I'm actually asking people to write programs.